# Define series using stream in scala

Tags: scala, math, stream, series

I wonder is there any possibility to define an infinite series using scala `Stream`'s

I've tried next:

```
Stream.tabulate(Int.MaxValue)(n => func(n))
```

where `func` is the function that calculate single member of a series(e.g `1 / n!` for calculating `e`)

But it's not actually correct. Because this series will have as maximum `Int.MaxValue` members. This might be enough for series that converges absolutely. But what if series has positive as well as negative members(possibly not alternating one).

PS I want to use such series in next way

```
val stream = Stream.tabulate(Int.MaxValue)(n => func(n))
val seriesSum = 
(stream zip stream.tail).takeWhile{case(a, b) => abs(abs(a) - abs(b)) > Error}.map(_._1).sum
```

where `Error` is for example 0.00001

What should I use instead of `Stream.tabulate`?

Answer (score 7):

You can pretty straightforwardly do this kind of thing with a combination of `Stream.iterate` and `scanLeft`:

```
def factorial(n: BigInt): BigInt = (BigInt(1) to n).reduceLeft(_ * _)

def factorials = Stream.iterate(BigInt(1))(_ + 1).map(factorial)

def values = factorials.scanLeft(BigDecimal(0))(_ + 1 / BigDecimal(_))
```

And then:

```
scala> values.take(10).foreach(println)
0
1
1.5
1.6666666666666666666666666666666667
1.70833333333333333333333333333333337
1.716666666666666666666666666666666703
1.718055555555555555555555555555555592
1.7182539682539682539682539682539682904
1.71827876984126984126984126984126987770
1.718281525573192239858906525573192276289
```

As expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with the infinite stream of naturals, and use map.

```
Stream.from(0).map(func)
```

Comment: it's actually also limited to Int.MaxValue. Because after `start = Int.MaxValue` this function adds 1 to it and we get Int.MinValue

Comment: it would be great to have such function for Long or BigInt

Comment: right, stupid me. Well if you intend to build with a function on int, the limitation is built-in anyway. You could build a stream of Longs (or BigInt) with def longNaturals = Stream.iterate(0L)(n => n + 1)